# Clone an Instantiated Object many times Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of prefabs, the script below instantiate 10 of them randomly in the Y axis.

The instantiated prefabs are random and different, but I want them to be same (clones of one prefab), how can I do that?

Script:

```
    public GameObject[] Bricks;

void Start () {

        SpawnCubes();
    }

void SpawnBricks(int numCubes = 10, float startY = 3, float delta = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i)
        {
            int Rand = Random.Range(0, Bricks.Length);
            var Brick = Instantiate(Bricks[Rand], new Vector3(0, startY - (float)i * delta, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            Brick.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fill `Bricks` with only one prefab? Or change `Bricks[Rand]` to `Bricks[0]`???

Comment: @Mars I want to spawn 10 bricks that are similar.

Comment: @Mars If I use Bricks[0], it will instantiate the same prefab every time, I want to instantiate random prefab then 9 copies of it, something like that.

Comment: but I want them to be same (clones of one prefab) 
What do you mean ?

Comment: @TimChang I want to instantiate a random prefab from the list of prefabs, then make 9 copies of it.

Comment: Then move `int Rand = ...` outside of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void SpawnBricks(int numCubes = 10, float startY = 3, float delta = 1)
{
    int Rand = Random.Range(0, Bricks.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i)
    {
        var Brick = Instantiate(Bricks[Rand], new Vector3(0, startY - (float)i * delta, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Brick.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }
}
```

Like This??